# How to join unidirectional entities from the target side?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `Car` and `CarType` entities involved in a unidirectional relationship as follows:

```
public class Car {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private CarType type;
  
  //other fields / getters / setters
}

public class CarType {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String code;

  //other fields / getters / setters

}
```

This unidirectional relationship has worked well to meet the requirements. But now I have a new requirement to get the set of `CarType`s for given set of `Car` ids.

How can I do this without using a native query and without creating a bidirectional relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```java
@Query("select c.type from Car c where c.id in (:ids)")
List<CarType> findCarTypesFor(List<Long> ids)
```